# Display onload? What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript

```
    <div onload="showHidden();">
    aa
    </div>

    <div id="cantseeme" style="display: none;">LALALA</div>

<script>
      function showHidden() {
        document.getElementById("cantseeme").style.display='inline'; // Show it
      }
</script>
```

I'm trying it here: http://jsfiddle.net/Lisandro/7jMGH/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onload` is not an attribute of the `div` element. It is only an attribute of the `body` element.

Answer (score 1):

At the time showHidden() is called, the browser has not yet loaded the script that defines that function. You need to place the function definition before the call to it, or wait to call the function until after the script has loaded.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div>
    aa
</div>

<div id="cantseeme" style="display: none;">LALALA</div>

<script>
        document.getElementById("cantseeme").style.display='inline'; // Show it
</script>
```

The script should load after the div so no need to worry about calling it.

I think.

http://jsfiddle.net/7jMGH/4/

Answer (score 1):

There is no div "onload" 
You can add to your body onload and it should work.